# Laravel 6 Logging in with wrong password causes file_put_contents error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel 6 and the default auth package scaffolding.

Registration works fine. The new users shows in the DB.
Logging in with the correct PW successfully takes me to the home page but I've got a problem when entering a wrong password.

It causes this error instead of complaining that the PW is wrong and this error is so vague.

Things tried:
 1. Changing folder permission 775

Untouched files:
HomeController.php, login.blade.php(css stuff only), register.blade.php, home.blade.php

There we're only some additional files and have their own controller and IMO has nothing to do with this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing folder permission 777 fixed it but this is bad solution, right?

Comment: Yes, you should make your httpd use propr user, instead if i. E. `www-data`